# Making GWT RPC play along with Guice

Tags: java, gwt, guice

This is the web.xml in my GWT app:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>user-base-url</param-name>
   <param-value>/user/admin</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>static-base-url</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>manifest</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>   

<!-- JBoss Resteasy -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myapp.server.guice.ServeModule</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
<listener-class>
    com.myapp.server.guice.CustomGuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>  
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>  
    <param-value>/</param-value>  
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My question would be how would I make this usable for GWT-RPC also, as when I do this

**ServeModule:**

```
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
    bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    serve("/app/myservice").with(MyServiceImpl.class);          
}
```

For a RPC defined as:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("myservice")
public interface MyService extends RemoteService
```

As when the app loads it throws this error:

> [ERROR] javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlets must be bound as
>   singletons. Key[type=com.myapp.server.serviceimpl.MyServiceImpl,
>   annotation=[none]] was not bound in singleton scope. [ERROR]  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:104)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:102)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:172)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>   [ERROR]   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) [ERROR]
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:247)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:78)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
>   [ERROR]   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509) [ERROR]
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
>   [ERROR]   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
>   [ERROR]   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

- What could be wrong in my app configuration?
- What could have I missed setting up?

Answer (score 1):

Bind the implementation (*Impl) class to [@Singleton](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Singleton.html) scope, either in the `ServletModule`:

```
bind(MyServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
serve("/app/myservice").with(MyServiceImpl.class);
```

or by annotating the class itself, as suggested by [xybrek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896830/764326).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to annotate the RPC Service implementation with `@Singleton`

as in, `com.google.inject.Singleton`

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your "also when I do this" you may just be using the wrong Singleton declaration

```
@Override
public void configureServlets() {

    bind(ImageServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);
    serve("/images").with(ImageServlet.class);
```